# ImportError: No module named pdfkit

Tags: python, python-3.x, wkhtmltopdf, python-pdfkit

I am working on pdfkit library in python in order to create pdf file from html string. It works fine on my linux system but when i try to run it on windows server then it gives me error

```
pdfkit.from_string(html_string, output_dir)
```

and i get following error

```
import pdfkit
ImportError: No module named pdfkit
```

I installed `wkhtmltopdf` using .exe and `pdfkit` on windows using pip.

I also set path for `wkhtmltopdf` in environment variables.

Comment: Show us the output of `pip --version`

Comment: pip `9.0.1` and python version `3.6`

Comment: How about `python --version`?

Comment: try this first, `pip3 install pdfkit` and let us know.

Comment: added python version above already !

Comment: Can you try to re-install the package using `pip install --ignore-installed pdfkit` and provide the output to that re-install command?

Comment: no i was replying to @JohnGordon .. i tried installing pdfkit with pip3 command and it shows me `could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pdfkit`

Comment: @mattdonders i tried and it installed successfully as it happens before

Comment: it might sound ridiculous, but check your spellings. I tried it for you just now; it's there; if you still can't get it, try as `admin`.

Comment: https://ibb.co/iMNdYm

I opened cmd in administrator mode and spelling is also correct !

Comment: @Ancient the screenshot above shows you typed `pdkit` twice instead of pdfkit, just an FYI. My command should have re-installed it if it was already installed so I assume you have it. The other thing you can try is open an interactive verbose python shell via `python -v` and then type the following commands - `import sys` `sys.version_info` `import pdfkit` and it should provide a verbose output.

Comment: still same error @mattdonders

Comment: @Ancient can you provide the output from those commands (in a screenshot or some other link)?

Answer (score 1):

***Yaa***, the main issue is, it may unable to find out the absolute path because of permission in windows, just try with administrator privileges as well give permission to directories to traversal.

for simple, you can do, copy the executable into your current directory :) :-)

or use the below lines in your code

```
path_wkthmltopdf = 'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkthmltopdf)

pdfkit.from_string(html_string, output_file, configuration=config)
```

If you are using Anaconda cloud, you can install pdfkit using 
`conda install -c conda-forge python-pdfkit`

or 
`conda install -c bioconda wkhtmltopdf`

for more details you can go through below links

***Docs***

1: [wkhtmltopdf](https://pypi.org/project/wkhtmltopdf/)

2: [pdfkit](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/)

Answer (score 1):

Besides the previous answer, I had the same problem. I was using a Virtual Environment and I was installing Pdfkit to the Global Python config, but I had to install it inside the Virtual Environment.

```
(myvenv) C:\Users\user1\Documents\python-project> pip install pdfkit
```

or

```
(myvenv) C:\Users\user1\Documents\python-project> C:\Users\user1\Documents\python-project/myvenv/Scripts/python.exe -m pip install pdfkit
```